# Injecting resolves into directive controllers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularUI router (0.2.13) and have a state defined as such

```
.state('foo', { 
    template:'<div some-directive></div>', 
    resolve: {
        foo: function(SomeService) {
            return SomeService.something().promise;
        }
    }
})
```

and a directive like this:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function(){
     return {
         controller: function(data) {
           // I want `data` to be injected from the resolve... 
           // as it would if this was a "standalone" controller
         }
     }
})
```

but this doesn't work - the `data` parameter causes an `UnknownProvider` error. Defining the directive controller independently and setting it by name in the directive has the same result.

I more or less get why this is happening, but have two questions:

1. is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?
2. should I be trying to do it, or have I slipped into an antipattern here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't use resolves in directives, but you can pass the result resolved in the state down to the directive which I think accomplishes what you're looking for.

You'd want to update your state definition to include a controller and set a parameter on the directive:

```
.state('foo', { 
   template:'Test<div some-directive something="foo"></div>',
   url: 'foo',
   resolve:{
       foo:function(SomeService){
           return SomeService.something();
       }
   },
   controller: function($scope, foo){
     $scope.foo = foo;
   }
})
```

Then update the directive to use this parameter:

```
.directive('someDirective', function(){
     return {
         controller: function($scope) {
           // I want `data` to be injected from the resolve... 
           // as it would if this was a "standalone" controller
           console.log('$scope.something: '+ $scope.something);
         },
         scope: {
           something: '='
         }
     };
})
```

Here's a sample plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TOPMLUXc7GhXTeYL0IFj?p=preview

Comment: sorry for the late accept. This was a great answer - had decided to go almost the exact same way before seeing it.

Comment: How would I do this if my template was an element directive e.g. '<my-directive></my-directive>' instead of an attribute directive? It seems that the controller defined here isnt firing in that case. The directive itself has an controller inside.....

Comment: @Brad Barber I +1 with Mathias Max here, it seems if the directive is a element, the resolve doesn't work. This is weird, no ?

Comment: I'm able to update the plunker from the answer above with the directive as an element and I don't see an issue. Are you using an older version of angular where directives are restricted to attributes by default? Is so, set `restrict = 'AE'` in the directive definition.

Answer (score 2):

They simplified the api. See this thread:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2664#issuecomment-204593098

> in 0.2.19 we are adding $resolve to the $scope, allowing you to do "route to component template" style
>
> template: `<my-directive input="$resolve.simpleObj"></my-directive>`,