# Passing params into angular directive controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a controller which has some custom UI router resolve params injected:

```
uxgroups.controller('UXGroupStepCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', 'stepData', function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, stepData) {
```

But when using this controller in my directive I am getting errors that stepData is undefined:

```
angular.js:14682 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=stepDataProvider%20%3C-%20stepData%20%3C-%20UXGroupStepCtrl%20%3C-%20UXGroupStepCtrl
```

which is :

```
Unknown provider: stepDataProvider <- stepData <- UXGroupStepCtrl <- UXGroupStepCtrl
```

Here is directive definition:

```
app.directive('passProcess', function (stepData) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'UXGroupStepCtrl',
        scope: { p: '=' },
        templateUrl: '/App/Modules/UXGroup/Views/process.html'
    };
});
```

Is there a way to dismiss or define the extra params in my directive controller?

Comment: I edited question, if you follow your error message link, error is obvious `Unknown provider: stepDataProvider <- stepData <- UXGroupStepCtrl <- UXGroupStepCtrl`

Comment: Thanks, though i know the error just not how to resolve

Comment: Probably you don't include lib for `stepData ` in script tags regularly

Comment: no, its not a library defined in script, it refers to data passed in a resolve statement on ui-router

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass data to controller from a directive like that. But the controller has the same scope as the directive. So what you can do is set a $scope variable in the directive and reference it in the controller.

```
app.directive('passProcess', function (stepData) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'UXGroupStepCtrl',
    scope: { p: '=' },
    templateUrl: '/App/Modules/UXGroup/Views/process.html'
};
});
uxgroups.controller('UXGroupStepCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$stateParams',
 function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.variable = $scope.p
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to pass data from directive to controller, I have a resolve item passed from UI-router into my controller which is causing errors when used in directive

Comment: You should have a separate controller for your directive so that it can be configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this other question [Injecting resolves into directive controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178305/injecting-resolves-into-directive-controllers)
which suggests it cannot be done, and best way is to make a separate controller for the directive